# running google chrome super slow on surface book

Tags: google-chrome, window, microsoft-surface

i bought a new surface book and running google chrome, is very laggy and freezes very regularly, e.g. switching from one tab to another takes 3 seconds. While running Microsoft Edge seems to be very smooth. I'm very disappointed about the performance of Surface book being one of the top high end laptop. Is my surface book a broken build? It also took like 1 second for my windows file explorer to open. Should i return my laptop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to advanced option -> Turn off Hardware acceleration solves to problem for me.

Comment: We always appreciate the contributions from our community members, but can you please elaborate on that answer?  Where are these advanced options:  within the Chrome browser itself, or somewhere in Windows 10?

Comment: @Run5k In Chrome browser: Settings -> Advanced -> use hardware acceleration where available.

Comment: @neilfws I appreciate your feedback.  As you might imagine, I could have done some research and discovered the answer myself.  When I originally posted this (14 months ago), my goal was to encourage the OP to edit his answer with much more thorough instructions for the benefit of other community members who might see this in the future.  Unfortunately, that never happened.  Once again, thanks for chiming in!

Comment: It doesn't work for me. If anything, rendering is even worse.